# Custom control not working with knockout "with" binding

Tags: knockout.js, custom-controls, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am new to knockout. My requirement is to place a custom control inside a div which is binded using "with". Below is the code I am using,

```
<div id="test" data-bind="with:testTemp">

     --------  I have placed my custom control here ---------

   --------- I am binding value to this custom control using "value" binding----

</div>
```

In Script,

```
function ViewModel() {

    this.testTemp= ko.observable();
    this.testTemp({
        price : 6.6
    });  
}
```

Now the value 6.6 is binded to the custom control, but it seems the control is not working more. Custom control is nothing but a editor percentage texbox, I am not able to increment/decrement the value. It seems to be occurring only when i bind the div using "with" binding. It is working fine without "with" binding in parent div. So, can anyone please let me know what I went wrong with the above code. Why my custom control fails to work with div using "with" binding. Do I need to add anything in my coding?

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your html where you are binding?

Comment: please add code on your custom control binding.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="test" data-bind="with:testTemp">
    <span data-bind="text : $data.price"></span>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.testTemp= ko.observable();
    this.testTemp({
        price : 6.6
    });  
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2pfn/)